# Creating package folder in Android/data with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package, internal-storage

I'm trying to create a package folder for my application but i can't understand why I can't find it.

I've set the permission `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` and I've tried with theese samples called in the MainActivity.onCreate().

```
//sample 1
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "folder");
boolean created1 = myDir.mkdir(); //this returns True
boolean created2 = myDir.mkdirs(); //this returns False

//sample 2
File myDir = this.getFilesDir();
File documentsFolder = new File(myDir, "documents/data");
boolean Created3 = documentsFolder.mkdirs(); //this returns True
```

The application is always cleaned and rebuild before each test but when I look for the folder in Android/data i can see the package folders of the other applications but not the mine.

I've read somewhere that I could see it only with a rooted device but in this case why can I see the folders of the other applications? I can't understand :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code instead:

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
             + "/folder_name");
myDir.mkdir();
```

Comment: i've this warning but i've not a sd in the phone: W/System.err: mkdir failed: EACCES (Permission denied) :     /storage/emulated/0/new_app_folder

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: i've also found this if it can be useful: W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/test.testapplication-2/lib/arm64

Comment: I tried the same on my phone now and it created a folder without any error. Can you check the permission again "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: what version of android are you using?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  Galaxy S7 Android 6.0.1      Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: you need to use runtime permission in Marshmallow. check app info from settings menu and check the appropriate permissions

Comment: It works, I didn't think about it, thank you so much! But this way I create it in the root folder, to create the default package folder in /Android/data (com.package_name) how can I do?

Comment: you can change the path to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Android/data/com.package_name/folder_name"